# javascript: selecting the biggest value

Tags: javascript

Very simple javascript question.

I have two values `value1 = 20` and `value2 = 30`

how can I assign to `bigger_number` variable the value with the higher number?

Comment: What did you try? I don't mean to be rude, but this is such a fundamental capability of any programming language it's hard to help you. Just giving you the line of code doesn't seem to be enough, we need to understand what you don't get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bigger_number = Math.max(value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bigger_number = Math.max(value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little google search gives reference to [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

e.g.:

```
Math.max([value1[,value2[, ...]]])
```